# Reverse header files / linking

Tags: c++, header, winsock

I have some beginner's question regarding c++.
I've downloaded windows SDK and according to the documentation, all bluetooth traffic uses winsock. Windows SDK includes header files (.h) if I want to program a bluetooth interface.

a) This is a general c++ question: how does the header file winsock.h gets linked to a specific dll? I didn't specify any link. How can I detect all the .dll that are linked with this header? 
Isn't the header file suppose to contain only the names of the functions and the actual implementation in the dll? I'm slightly confused.

My second goal is to replace the windows winsock functions by a modified version. I would like to keep the original functionality, unless some flag, set by a different application, is set to true. In this case, I want to modify some functions.
My approach is to create a new dll, that will have the same function names, as shown in the header file winsock.h .

b) Assume that there exists a function fff in the original winsock. I'll replace it with a new function, that unless the flag is true, calls the same function fff but in the unmodified dll, i.e..  I want in this case to "include" the original function from the unmodified dll and "overload" my modified fff function, with the original fff function. This two functions have the same parameters, and the same name. How do I that? Is there a better way to achieve the same goal?

c) what is the best way (or the easy way) to allow the flag, set by an application, to be accessible within the dll?

d) Winsocket is a very central component. Should I expect a major performance deterioration if I add one if command to every function in it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

a) The header file simply defines things (types, functions, classes) that are to be found elsewhere - it does not specify where. When you link the program you include .lib files which contain (among other things) the connection to the correct DLL. When the program runs the lib code will load the DLL into memory and connect to it.

b) Generate a second DLL that contains all the same functions as in winsock but with (say) ELI_ added to the start of the function name. Then inside the ELI_ function look at the flag and if it's not set call the basic winsock function, otherwise do whatever special thing you have in mind.

c) Make the flag variable a global static variable within your ELI_ DLL code, then add extra functions to set the flag (and read back its state, probably)

d) I don't know, but a single if is not going to take very much time at all. I would be more worried about what your special code does.

Comment: Don't agree with a). In MS (and compatible) compilers, there are pragmas to define what library is used. E.g. `#pragma comment(lib, "foo.lib")` can be added to a headerfile.

Comment: @Mats I get your point - the pragma allows the .h to specify the library file - but I feel it doesn't change the basic point I was trying to make about what header and .lib files (generally) do.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying, and generally it applies. However, particularly MS has a tendency to add these sort of pragmas to their headerfiles. Which can be quite confusing to some people, because "it automagically works", and then on a different platform, "you need to do things to make libraries work">

Comment: Also, when I manipulate the static variable, does the change applies to any program that previously loaded the dll, or any function that will call it in the future?

Comment: Let me clarify my intention: I want to modify the winsocket dll. Say If the flag COUNT_CONNECT is true, then I want to count the number of calls, by any process, to the  the socket function connect. As other processes will try to call the connect function rather than connect_ELI, shouldn't I name my function connect as well? If so, after I increased the counter, how do I call the original connect function from Microsoft dll, from my modified dll, with the same function name (connect)?

Comment: You cannot do this (at least I think you cannot do so at all easily). Other programs will as you say use the standard function names and the lib files (or ticks such as Mat's above) will specify the DLL that holds those functions.

Comment: Alternatively, I was told that I might try to use hooks. As I know virtually nothing about it, what are the pros and cons of each technique (hooking vs. modifing the ws32 dll)?

Comment: A hook allows you to place yourself between other programs and the operating system code that does the work. So for example a keyboard hook function will be called every time a key is pressed and you would also have info on where the key was to be sent. So you can modify keys or whatever. But (I think) you can only hook things for which a hook mechanism is provided ... so if the hook(s) you want are there this would work very nicely, otherwise it isn't going to help you.

Comment: A quick bit of research shows that you can certainly hook winsock connect. I would recommend that you try doing it this way.